# Looking to create a network based on bee floral visitation in Rstudio

Tags: r

I am looking to create a network showing different bees visiting different flowers. I have been using the igraph r package and believe it should be a bipartite network.

looking for something that looks like this with thicker bars indicating more visitations and thinner bars showing less visitations:

[image: looking for something that looks like this with thicker bars indicating more visitations and thinner bars showing less visitations]

Part of my dataset is shown here with floral species on the left and bee species along the top with visitation numbers shown in the table.

[image: My data set is set up as shown here with floral species on the left and bee species along the top with visitation numbers shown in the table.]

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to set up my data table or how to go about getting my bipartite network with bee species on one side and floral species on the other. Is using the igraph package the best way to do this?

[image: I have been able to create a network that looks like this however it does not include the names of any of the species or thinner/thicker lines.]

This was the code used to get the network:

```
bg=graph_from_incidence_matrix(floral_network_)
bg

V(bg)$type

V(bg)$type+1

V(bg)$shape=c("square","circle")[V(bg)$type+1] V(bg)$color=c("tomato","lightblue")[V(bg)$type+1] plot(bg)

plot(bg, layout=layout_as_bipartite(bg), edge.color="black", edge.width=4,vertex.label.dist=1, vertex.label.degree=c(rep(-pi/2, 4), rep(pi/2, 5)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data is nor reproducible (since it is an image), but here is a reproducible version:

```r
floral_network_ <- structure(list(bimac = c(2L, 16L, 9L, 4L, 1L), borealis = c(0L, 
7L, 0L, 0L, 1L), ferv = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), griseocolli = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), impatiens = c(9L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 0L), perplexus = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rufocinctu = c(0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ternarius = c(0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L), vagans = c(0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("Elaeagnus_umbellata", 
"Symphytum_officinale", "Hypericum_perforatum", "Glechoma_hederacea", 
"Trifolium_pratense"))
```

To get the freedom to plot this as you would like, I think it would be best to reshape your data and plot with `ggplot`

```
library(tidyverse)

as.data.frame(as.table(as.matrix(floral_network_))) %>%
  filter(Freq > 0) %>%
  rename(Flower = Var1, Bee = Var2) %>%
  mutate(bee_pos_x = as.numeric(factor(Bee)),
         flower_pos_x = as.numeric(factor(Flower)) * 6/4 - 0.5,
         bee_pos_y = 2, flower_pos_y = 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(bee_pos_x, bee_pos_y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = bee_pos_x, y = bee_pos_y, xend = flower_pos_x,
                   yend = flower_pos_y, size = Freq), colour = "red",
               alpha = 0.2, lineend = "round") +
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "yellow2", size = 8) +
  geom_point(aes(flower_pos_x, flower_pos_y), size = 9, shape = 21,
             fill = "deepskyblue2") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Bee), nudge_y = 0.1) +
  geom_text(aes(flower_pos_x, flower_pos_y, label = Flower), nudge_y = -0.1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.5, 2.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 8)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]